# Why does setting a MinimumSize break the table layout?

Tags: c#, winforms, layout

I'm currently playing around with layouts and made a test project where I construct a Form which displays a Panel which contains a TableLayoutPanel with three rows:

- a text box
- a button
- a placeholder label which is supposed to take up the remaining vertical space.

This test works properly, but if I set the Minimum Size of the Text Box to e.g. (400, 200), I can no longer see the button. Shouldn't the first row in the table layout AutoSize to its content? Note that 
setting RowStyles explicitly to `SizeType.AutoSize` doesn't change anything.

---

No minimum size set:

[image: Screenshot where the text box and button are visible]

Minimum size set:

[image: Screenshot where the button is hidden behind the text box]

---

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LayoutTest
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            var sampleForm = new Form();
            var samplePanel = new Panel() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            var sampleTextBox = new TextBox() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            // This line breaks the layout
            //sampleTextBox.MinimumSize = new Size(400, 200);
            var sampleButton = new Button() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };

            var panelLayout = new TableLayoutPanel() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            panelLayout.Controls.Add(sampleTextBox, 0, 0);
            panelLayout.Controls.Add(sampleButton, 0, 1);
            // Add a placeholder label to take up the remaining space
            panelLayout.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = String.Empty, Dock = DockStyle.Fill });

            samplePanel.Controls.Add(panelLayout);

            sampleForm.Controls.Add(samplePanel);

            Application.Run(sampleForm);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are expecting the TableLayoutPanel to do its job, layout controls in a table arrangement, without telling it *how* to do its job.  Add rows.  This goes wrong because of the TextBox.GetPreferredSize() return value.  Use the designer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The button is underneath the textbox. You need to set the `multiline` property to `true`.

E.g.

```
sampleTextBox.Multiline = true;
```

The source of this behavior is either the `TableLayoutPanel` or the `TextBox`. It would be strange for the `TableLayoutPanel` to explicitly test if a `Control` is a `TextBox` and if `Multiline` property is set to `true` before deciding to adhere to the the `MinimumSize` constraint. However, in my testing, it appears that the `Multiline` property must be set before adding it to the `TableLayoutPanel` and if `Multiline` is unset, then the control goes back underneath the text box and never goes back even if `Multiline` is set to true again.

E.g.

```
        sampleButton.Click += delegate {
            Size s1 = sampleTextBox.MinimumSize; // always returns the set MinSize
            sampleTextBox.Multiline = !sampleTextBox.Multiline;
            Size s2 = sampleTextBox.MinimumSize; // always returns the set MinSize
            panelLayout.Invalidate(true);
            panelLayout.PerformLayout();
        };
```

Comment: Looks like I picked the wrong control for testing ;-) Thanks for resolving this issue.

Comment: The `TableLayoutPanel` and `FlowLayoutPanel` don't behave as expected (e.g. your `TextBox` example). Also, the MSDN documentation doesn't provide enough information on all Properties that each `Layout` adheres to when it performs the layout.